# How to Convert String to Array Object inside Java Script for JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, eval

I have a string Variable in javascript which contains a parsed data from a STATIC XML.
The data is parsed in this format:
val2 = "[{account:'ss',order:'ss'},{account:'f',order:'f'}]"

I need to convert this string variable as Array Object as an input for "DATA" in jqGrid.

I tried to perform val3 = JSON.parse(val2) and got an error: 'Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2'

I need to remove the '"' from val2 to be converted as an array.

Eg: 
val4 = [{account:'ss',order:'ss'},{account:'f',order:'f'}]

This will be converted to Array Object.

I did some more research and below is the **solution**:

From static XML, read in following format (Remember ***NOT*** to include **[** and **]** in the first string variable)

val2 = "{account:'ss',order:'ss'},{account:'f',order:'f'}"
val3 = **eval**("[" + val2 + "]")

This will convert the string to Array Object which is acceptable by jqGrid.

[Convert String to Array Object inside Java Script for JQGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WelSR.jpg)

Comment: Please insert your question in here, don't just paste an image

Comment: Please don't post links to screenshots as your question.  Type your question out.

Comment: This would be a good time to read [ask]

Comment: Nice work on the image, but some actual context and a question written out where we can see it without going to an external source would be nice.

Comment: I posted the question in TEXT format.
Also posted the Solution which i did some research while posting the question.

Appreciate if you can verify if my answer is correct.

Also if there is any alternative GOOD workaround for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

please read my answer for question in this link. this is having answer of your question.

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/39560256/5382854
[question] [why i cannot assign an array to jqgrid columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558993/why-i-cannot-assign-an-array-to-jqgrid-columns/39560256#39560256)