# why i cannot assign an array to jqgrid columns?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i have wrriten the following code to generate columns and column model from an array, whats funny is when i hard code the generated array in jqgrid like below  it generates teh columns but when put the array to a variable and then assign it to colModel it wont generate the columns. why is that and how do i fix this?

the complete code is at the bottom

im using JQGrid by http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"

**Here is the hard coded code:**

```
//hard coding the array
    $('#myGrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 250,
        //colNames:modelArr,
        colModel:[{name:' 9/10/2014'}, {name:' 1/1/2014'}, {name:' 2/10/2014'}],
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: true,
        caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
    });
```

**Here is the complete code:**

```
    var colsArray =[];
    var modelArr = [];

    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:53721/Home/GetPurchases',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            colsArray=data;

            var str='';

            if(data.length > 0 ){
                str = data[0].PurchaseDates;
                console.log(str);
               colsArray = str.split(',');
            }


            for(var i=0; i < colsArray.length;i++){
                var tmp = {name:colsArray[i]};
                modelArr[i]=tmp;
            }

            //console.log(JSON.stringify(modelArr));

        },
        error:function(){}

    });

    var d1 = JSON.stringify(modelArr);
    console.log(d1);

    $('#myGrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 250,
        //colNames:modelArr,
        colModel:[modelArr],         //[{name:' 9/10/2014'}, {name:' 1/1/2014'}, {name:' 2/10/2014'}],
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: true,
        caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is working when you hardcode it : colModel need an array but when you trying to make it dynamically , its coming as String.

```
//use below methods:
// call below functions at grid
----
----
colNames:getColNames(result.colNames), //["Plan_code", "LOB"],
colModel:getColModels(result.colNames),
----
----

//define these function
function getColNames(columndata) {
    var keys = [];
    for(var key in columndata) {
        if (columndata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keys.push(columndata[key]);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}

function  getColModels(modelData) {
    var colNames= getColNames(modelData);
    var colModelsArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++) {
        var str;
        if (i === 0) {
            str = {
                name: colNames[i],
                index:colNames[i],
                key:true,
                editable:true
            };
        } else {
            str = {
                name: colNames[i],
                index:colNames[i],
                editable:true
            };
        }
        colModelsArray.push(str);
    }

    return colModelsArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the square brackets when you assign the colModel to an array, because keeping it will produce an array of array.

```
var myGrid = $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colModel:modelArr,
    viewrecords: true,
    multiselect: true,
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
});
```

here's a working [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/vzwf9gxn/4/) using your provided code.

I also added two lines at the end of the sample to show the difference between the two assignment shapes as shown in the below image

[image: array vs array of array]